# Convert string into key/value pairs for $.post()

Tags: jquery

I want to have the same result as this line of code:

```
 $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

How do I convert a string variable

```
 var str = '{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }';
```

into key/value pairs so that I can send the POST request using this line of code:

```
 $.post("test.php", str );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built in method specifically for this,

[parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a string to a JSON object try this:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(str );
```

so your code would look like:

```
$.post("test.php", jQuery.parseJSON(str ));
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

use $.ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: str,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(e) {
        //Function here onsucess            
    }
});
```